# Search map Listing

Tags: here-api

I used the search app on this https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples

When I search any Location name. There are not list in search app. I have seen your app.There are searching list. I am attaching screen shot as search location. 
**How to achieve this with the help of above GitHub code**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use TextAutoSuggest search, this will trigger the callback already on partial search input if wanted. See example and doc https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-premium/topics/places.html  (section: Text AutoSuggestion Requests)

Comment: @Macro I read this Text AutoSuggestion Requests but didCompleteWithData  NMAResultListener Not working offline It is working only online. So we can only use it for online

Comment: Yes, AutoSuggest is a online only feature at the moment.